# Does Ember have a some() method like Dojo

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Does Ember have a some() method like Dojo

I am trying to run the below code;

```
obj.view = someObj.forEach(function(tempArr){
    return (tempArr.actionName == "view") ? true : false ;
});
```

But since forEach does not terminate, the code does not work properly.

I want to exit at the first find (return true) So I want something similar to what DojoJS has dojo.some() https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/arrays.html#quickstart-arrays

In simple terms, I want to break and return true for the variable on first condition that is true (else return false for the variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_find), [findBy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_findBy) to get first element or [any](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_any) if you only need to have true/false.

```
obj.view = someArray.findBy('actionName', 'view');

// es6 shortened - carefull with implicit return statement
obj.view = someArray.find(item => item.get('actionName') === 'view');
obj.view = someArray.any(item => item.get('actionName') === 'view');

// es6 with () and {}    
obj.view = someArray.find((item) => {
    return item.get('actionName') === 'view';
});

// es5
obj.view = someArray.find(function(item){
    return item.get('actionName') === 'view';
});
```

Comment: Thx a lot...Is item => item.get('actionName') a new syntax ?

Comment: Yes, it's part of new es6 syntax. I added es5 into the answer.

Comment: also i assume this would loop through all items in my array (but till the first match is found)...i just need to return true/false value finally

Comment: If you only want to know if any of elements in array has ```actionName === view``` and don't care about what element has it. You can use [any](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_any) the same way you would use ```find```.